# Google PubSub error [code=8a75]

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Today, I started getting this error sporadically. Google pubsub error codes talks about only HTTP error codes. Does anyone know about this error?

ERROR Error: The service was unable to fulfill your request. Please try again. [code=8a75]

Comment: in comment

It seems that this error code is an issue/error in the Google Cluod Platform itself. You can verify it with these Github [issue1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1101) and [issue2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1309).

Answer (score 1):

This error code is retryable, and can be safely expected. Automating your code to automatically retry with backoff, or to use one of the official client libraries, which automatically retry on these errors with backoff is the recommended solution.

In general these errors should be independent, meaning after a retry or two the odds that your RPC fails should be very low.