# Google PubSub python client returning StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to establish a long running Pull subscription to a Google Cloud PubSub topic.
I am using a code very similar to the example given in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#pubsub-pull-messages-async-python), i.e.:

```
def receive_messages(project, subscription_name):
    """Receives messages from a pull subscription."""
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        message.ack()

    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

    # The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from
    # exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.
    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
```

The problem is that I'm receiving the following traceback sometimes:

```
Exception in thread Consumer helper: consume bidirectional stream:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/path/to/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_consumer.py", line 248, in _blocking_consume
    self._policy.on_exception(exc)
  File "/path/to/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/policy/thread.py", line 135, in on_exception
    raise exception
  File "/path/to/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_consumer.py", line 234, in _blocking_consume
    for response in response_generator:
  File "/path/to/grpc/_channel.py", line 348, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/path/to/grpc/_channel.py", line 342, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, The service was unable to fulfill your request. Please try again. [code=8a75])>
```

I saw that this was referenced in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638468/google-pubsub-error-code-8a75) but here I am asking to how to handle it properly in Python. I have tried to wrap the request in an exception but it seems to run in the background and I am not able to retry in case of that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A somewhat hacky approach that is working for me is a custom [policy_class](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/pubsub-0.28.4/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/client.py#L39). The default one has an `on_exception` function that ignores `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`. You can make a class that inherits the default and also ignores `UNAVAILABLE`. Mine looks like this:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
from google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.policy import thread
import grpc

class AvailablePolicy(thread.Policy):
    def on_exception(self, exception):
        """The parent ignores DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. Let's also ignore UNAVAILABLE.

        I'm not sure what triggers that error, but if you ignore it, your
        subscriber seems to work just fine. It's probably an intermittent
        thing and it reconnects later if you just give it a chance.
        """
        # If this is UNAVAILABLE, then we want to retry.
        # That entails just returning None.
        unavailable = grpc.StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        if getattr(exception, 'code', lambda: None)() == unavailable:
            return
        # For anything else, fallback on super.
        super(AvailablePolicy, self).on_exception(exception)

subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient(policy_class=AvailablePolicy)
# Continue to set up as normal.
```

It looks a lot like the [original](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/pubsub-0.28.4/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/policy/thread.py#L128) `on_exception` just ignores a different error. If you want, you can add some logging whenever the exception is thrown and verify that everything still works. Future messages will still come through.

Comment: FWIW, there's a [cpu problem](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3965) after about an hour. I think the issue is a thread leak each time you ignore an error (others get it after `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED`), but I could not find a fix. I went back to using the old api and doing my own periodic pulling rather than using the stream stuff. [This example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-python/blob/master/cmdline-pull/pubsub_sample.py) was useful for setting that up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... seems extremely overkill for something that should be very easy. For the task at hand I ended up using `golang` client library which works like a charm

Comment: [Related issue on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/2683)